# como utilizar Expressoes/Funções SQL Server em um filter de um TFDQuery no delphi

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-xe8

Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso verificar se a hora de uma determinada tarefa ja nao esta preenchida no sistema e para isso realizando um comando SQL no SQL Server 2014 funciona, como no exemplo

```
Select (cast((convert(datetime,hora,108)) +'00:01:00.000' as time(7))) as tempo from MIGRACOES_INTE_HORA
```

OBS: realizo o convert para transformar a hora de `Varchar` para time...

porem no sistema utilizo a propriedade filter de uma `TFDQuery` para realizar a consulta, mais para otimizar a mesma.

no filter adiciono

```
(CAST((convert(datetime,'+TimeToStr(dtpInteHora.Time)+',108)) + '00:01:00.000', as time(7)) = '+DateToStr(qryInteHora.FieldByName('Hora').AsDateTime)+') or
(CAST((convert(datetime,'+TimeToStr(dtpInteHora.Time)+',108)) - '00:01:00.000', as time(7)) = '+DateToStr(qryInteHora.FieldByName('Hora').AsDateTime)+')
```

mas quando ativo o filtro vem o seguinte erro

```
[FireDAC][Stan][Eval]-100. Column or function [CAST] is not found. Hint: if the name is a function name, then add FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs to uses clause.
```

Alguém saberia me dizer como posso realizar este filtro??

Answer (score 2):

Amigo,

Pesquisei aqui rápido, mas não consegui a confirmação, no entanto, acredito que o Filter do TFDQuery é aplicado apenas a registro já carregados do seu DataSet. Ele não aplica isso diretamente no seu banco. Suas consultas são limitadas.

No seu caso, acredito que terá que aplicar o filter como consulta da sua query, para que seu banco seja o responsável por isso.

Comment: sim o filter sao aplicados a registros ja carregados, só que preciso realizar uma validação quanto a data e nao consigo utilizar o cast, convert entre outras funções SQL no filter... Para resovler esse problema tive que colocar outra query puxando os registros com a expressao necessaria. Obrigado pela resposta...